# Calculating quantiles in groups of 20 in large data frame R

Tags: r, iteration, quantile

I am trying to calculate quantiles in groups of 20 rows for a very large dataset (over 40,000 rows). I would also like for the results to be written in one .csv file.

I am able to calculate what I need using slice notation like this:

```
    my_data<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)

    q1<-my_data[1:20,"Q"]
    q2<-my_data[21:40,"Q"]

    quant1<-quantile(q1,c(0.5,0.75,0.8,0.9,0.95))
    quant2<-quantile(q2,c(0.5,0.75,0.8,0.9,0.95))

    d=data.frame(quant1,quant2)

    write.csv(d,file="q_values.csv")
```

however, this will get extremely cumbersome and time-consuming to re-write these lines for the entire dataset. I'd like to somehow iterate through the data so that it calculates what I need for every 20 rows, but I cannot seem to understand how to do this. I've read through help files for "for" loops in R, but I'm still at novice level when it comes to coding and would greatly appreciate some guidance on how to do this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a column to index by, you can do this pretty easily. Here is an example using data.table.

```
dat <- data.table(Q = rnorm(40000))
dat[, R := rep(1:(.N/20), each = 20)]
dat[, .(quant_0.5 = quantile(Q, probs = c(0.5)),
        quant_0.75 = quantile(Q, probs = c(0.75)),
        quant_0.8 = quantile(Q, probs = c(0.8)),
        quant_0.9 = quantile(Q, probs = c(0.9)),
        quant_0.95 = quantile(Q, probs = c(0.95))), 
    by = R]
```

Which gives result:

```
         R    quant_0.5 quant_0.75 quant_0.8 quant_0.9 quant_0.95
   1:    1 -0.123822327  0.4609870 0.5784939 1.0898441  1.1224632
   2:    2 -0.251293742  0.3701377 0.7802016 1.0747215  1.5514140
   3:    3 -0.070979910  0.4268033 0.5546480 1.4477840  1.5304469
   4:    4  0.177552739  0.8687846 1.0001809 1.3883132  1.5394739
   5:    5  0.515836825  0.9611607 1.1268148 1.3396512  1.5087827
  ---                                                            
1996: 1996  0.566311407  1.0667204 1.3171846 1.5641837  1.8594775
1997: 1997  0.009336622  0.2859035 0.3397875 0.5472635  0.8108932
1998: 1998  0.514867828  1.0330679 1.0534716 1.2528384  2.0933062
1999: 1999  0.247092220  0.7501609 0.8924200 1.1446394  1.4736887
2000: 2000 -0.076496868  0.6816951 0.7430764 0.8362260  1.1001702
```

Comment: Thank you Eric!! I had never heard of data.table before and this worked out great! Although I first had to convert my data frame to a data table with as.data.table. I also got stuck as I had several nan in my datafile that I didn't realize were there, so I had to address those before the script would work. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. Lots of ways to do this, I just default to data.table since I am often using that rather than data.frames. In particular, the package dplyr would give similar results as above using data.frames, but very different syntax. Either way, having the column to index by is helpful.

If you like data.table, trying using the function `fread`. 

    `my_data <- fread(file.choose())`

It will read in your csv, often a lot faster than read.csv will, and create the data.table all in one go.